# Variable Assignment of Nested Promise Not Resolving (Stripe API)

Tags: javascript, promise, stripe-payments, javascript-objects

Using the Stripe API, I am calling all products `stripe.products.list()`, and then attempting to append pricing data `stripe.prices.list()` for each product using the `map()` function. Each call returns a promise, although the nested promise is not resolving, and is instead returning an empty *prices* object. What am I missing?

```
export function handler(event, context, callback) {
    stripe.products
        .list()
        .then(products =>
            products.data.map(product => ({
                ...product,
                prices: stripe.prices                    //  <-- ASSIGNMENT NOT RESOLVED
                    .list({ product: product.id })
                    .then(prices => {
                        console.log(prices)              //  <-- RESOLVED IN CONSOLE
                        return prices
                    }),
            }))
        )
        .then(rsp => {
            callback(null, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(rsp),
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.warn(err))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.map` is executed synchronous and you are not awaiting the promises within `products.data.map`. The `prices` object is not empty, it is a promise. The output in the console is generated only after the handler has already returned.

A simple way, would be the following. Ie store the received products in a variable. Then use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get the prices for all of the products. And then combine those two arrays for the final result.

```
export function handler(event, context, callback) { 
  let theproducts;
  stripe.products
    .list()
    .then(products => {
      theproducts = products.map(p => p.data);
      return Promise.all(products.data.map(product => 
          stripe.prices.list({ product: product.id }))
        )
     })
     .then(prices => theproducts.map((p, i) => ({...p, prices: prices[i]})
     .then(rsp => {
       callback(null, {
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
         statusCode: 200,
         body: JSON.stringify(rsp),
       })
      })
      .catch(err => console.warn(err))
}
```

You can also merge products and price immediately when `stripe.prices.list()` resolves and so spare an additional iteration of the map. But I personally find it more readable this way. And if you don't have too many products, the additonal iteration doesn't take too long.

Answer (score 1):

You are not awaiting for the internal promise to resolve:

```
export function handler(event, context, callback) {
    stripe.products
        .list()
        .then(products =>
            return Promise.all(products.data.map(product => {
                return stripe.prices                    //  <-- ASSIGNMENT NOT RESOLVED
                    .list({ product: product.id })
                    .then(prices => {
                        console.log(prices)              //  <-- RESOLVED IN CONSOLE
                        return prices
                    }),
            }))
            .then(prices => {
                return {
                    ...product,
                    prices
                };
            });
        )
        .then(rsp => {
            callback(null, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(rsp),
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.warn(err))
}
```

Comment: I got the gist of what you're doing. Had to reorder the closures.

Answer (score 0):

You have returned the array within products.data.map. However this is an array of promises. When you map them and chain the promise. It does not actually resolve the promise. I suggest you try some async syntax to simplify the code.

```
(async () => {
       const blah = products.data.map(product => {
            const prices = await stripe.prices.list({ product: product.id });
            return { ...product, prices };
        });
       console.log(blah);
})()
```

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks. I have updated my answer. Just want to give async syntax as an option

Comment: still won't work, because the callback of `map` is not an `async` function  (only the anonymous wrapper is) and you can only use `await` inside an `async` function ... And even if you define it async, `Array.map` is always executed synchronously, so it won't wait for the callbacks to resolve, but just return an array of promises. The only way to go here is using `Promise.all` or a `for (let p in products.data)` loop in an `async` function.

Answer (score 0):

With lots of helpful input, I ended up with the following.

```
export function handler(event, context, callback) {
    stripe.products
        .list()
        .then(products => {
            return Promise.all(
                products.data.map(product =>
                    stripe.prices
                        .list({ product: product.id })
                        .then(prices => {
                            return prices
                        })
                        .then(prices => {
                            return {
                                ...product,
                                prices,
                            }
                        })
                )
            )
        })
        .then(rsp => {
            callback(null, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(rsp),
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.warn(err))
}
```